# Javascript String Replace issue

Tags: javascript

I have the following code like

```
<div id="profile_description">
 <p>Some Text with\nNew Line</p>
</div>
```

Here is my Javascript code for replace \n to < br >console.log($('#profile_description_field').html());

```
var str = $('#profile_description').html();
console.log(str);
str = str.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br>');
console.log(str);
```

The output is always `Some Text with\nNew Line`

What I doing wrong here? I have tried so many things ...
I hope you have a idea. Thank you so much!

Comment: Are you using `Jquery` ?

Comment: `str.replace(/\\n/g, "<br>")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your text doesn't have a new line in it, it has a slash character followed by an n.

It works fine if you have a new line in the HTML.

```js
var str = $('#profile_description').html();
console.log(str);
str = str.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br>');
console.log(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="profile_description">
 <p>Some Text with
 New Line</p>
</div>
```

If you want to deal with your original HTML then you'll need to replace a slash followed by a the letter n, which means you have to escape the slash.

```js
var str = $('#profile_description').html();
console.log(str);
str = str.replace(/\\n/g, '<br>');
console.log(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="profile_description">
 <p>Some Text with\nNew Line</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Very great explanation and works now perfect.